# How to reach a WEBDAV mount in a NFS4 export

Tags: linux, debian, mount, nfs

I have a WEBDAV mountpoint to a remote server, the according user mountable directory is created in a directory, which i export via NFS4. Browsing the mounted share directory on a workstation (Debian Nautilus) does not list the files of the WEBDAV mount, only (..) the directory itself. It is writeable, but not present on the "real" endpoint.
SSHFS from my workstation to the NFS4 machine DOES list the correct files of the WEBDAV mount. But i want to make use of the faster connection via NFS4

At the NFS4 Server i have:

```
$ cat /etc/exports

/home/kione/BigB/    192.168.3.0/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,crossmnt)

$ cat /etc/fstab

https://webdav.endpoint.de/ /home/kione/BigB/mountDir   davfs        rw,user,noauto          0        0
```

At my Workstations i have:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab

192.168.3.61:/home/kione/BigB/ /home/kione/BigB nfs rw,noauto,user 0 0

$ ls BigB (nfs4 server)

mountDir

 - files
 - folders
```

At workstation with BigB mounted)

```
$ ls BigB 

mountDir = empty
```

My question is now, can someone help alter my parameters, or is this a no go... because SSHFS is working, but slower, you might have a next suggestion. Thank you for reading and all your thoughts.ki

Comment: I've attempted to neaten up your formatting with codeblocks (select what you want to format as code and hit the {} button, though I suspect you can make a few improvements. I've also changed your directory to something a little more worksafe while I was at it.

Comment: Visual is accurate, thanks for that Journeyman Geek. I checked out smb:// to my NFS4 Server, and the remote WEBDAV is full accessible. Please, clarify what you mean by "worksafe", I am not sure why you did shorten BigButt to BigB, especially the export doesn't make sense to me, now.

Comment: I changed all references to.. well the original path, to BigB cause occasionally folk complain about that sort of... well, juvenile humour. Consider it an alias ;). If you feel strongly about it, I suppose you can revert the original file name, but eventually someone will flag it and a mod would need to be involved. The question is fine otherwise so... I figured its a minor change not changing the intent of the question that would save trouble later.

Comment: :D i don't agree, butt i accept the changings... just to show my respect cause you read and took care on my question.